# Integrating over a scalar field

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have the scalar field $ p:\space \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R},\space \underline{x}\mapsto p(\underline{x}) $ which is continuous and differentiable. I don't know how I have to proceed to evaluate the following integral:
$$ \int_{\alpha} \frac{\operatorname{grad}(p(\underline{x}))}{p(\underline{x})}\  d\underline{x}.$$

If I would have this in the one dimensional case I just would have
$$ \int_{\alpha} \frac{\operatorname{grad}(p(x))}{p(x)}\  dx=\int_{\alpha} \frac{p'(x)}{p(x)}\  dx$$
and I would substitute with $ x=p(x) $.

Comment: Isn't your integrand equal to $\nabla(\ln p(\vec{x}))$? You should be able to show this via chain rule if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What is $\ln p(\vec{x} )$?

Comment: Just the natural log of $p(\underline{x}),$ I used the arrow because I didn't know how to do the underline

Comment: But why this expression ∇(lnp(x⃗ )) ?

Comment: Try computing the gradient and maybe you'll see

Comment: Yes I did this and get this $$ \frac{\operatorname{grad}(p((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T))}{p((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T)}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_1}((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T)}{p((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T)} \\\frac{\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_2}((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T)}{p((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T)} \\\frac{\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_3}((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T)}{p((x_1,x_2,x_3)^T)}\end{pmatrix}  $$. I still don't know how to integrate that.I'm only familiar with component wise integration with only one variable. But here are three different variables.

Comment: Okay, and when you compute the gradient of $\ln p(\underline{x})$?

Comment: Yes, I get this ugly gradient back. But what is that for a weird integration??

Comment: Presumably you're doing a line integral, right? If so then using the fact that your integrand is of the form $\nabla g$ should be immensely useful.

Comment: Yes, that is an integral over a line.

Comment: You're familiar with the Fundamental Theorem of Line Integation, yes? Try applying that

Comment: I know this theorem but my problem is the expression $ \frac{\operatorname{grad}(p(\underline{x}))}{p(\underline{x})} $. Until yet I was used to work with line integral only with $ \operatorname{grad}(p(\underline{x})) $.

Comment: Right, so if that expression can be rewritten as $\nabla[\ln p(\underline{x})]$ then...?

Comment: From here I'm confused. Do you mean the whole integral $ \int_{\alpha} \frac{\operatorname{grad}(p(\underline{x}))}{p(\underline{x})}\  d\underline{x} $ or just the integrand $ \frac{\operatorname{grad}(p(\underline{x}))}{p(\underline{x})} $?

Comment: Just the integrand

Comment: Ahhh! Now I see it. Thank you very much. :D